# Найти ошибки в коде

Tags: java, массивы

Нужно в массиве найти: максимальную длину без нулей, индекс первого эл-та исчисления максимальной длины.

```
 int[] luecke = {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1,0, 1, 0};
        int index = 0;
        int anzahl = 0;
        int maxLength = 0;
        int indexm = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < luecke.length; i++){
            if(luecke[i] != 0){
                for(int j = 0; j < luecke.length; j++){
                    if(luecke[j] > 0 && luecke[j - 1] == 0 && luecke[j] !=luecke[0]){
                        index = luecke[j];
                        anzahl++;
                    } else if(luecke[j] > 0){
                        anzahl++;
                    } else if(luecke[j] > 0 && luecke[j + 1] == 0){
                        maxLength = anzahl;
                        anzahl = 0;
                        indexm = index;
                        index = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Ответ будет тут - длина 6, а индекс 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Индексация массива начинается с нуля:

"Ответ будет тут - длинна 6, а индекс 6."

```js
function nonzero(arr) {
  var lenMax = 0, idxMax = 0;
  var len = 0, idx = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == 0) {
      if (len > lenMax) {
        lenMax = len;
        idxMax = idx;
      }
      len = 0;
      idx = i + 1;
    } else {
      len++;
    }
  }
  if (len > lenMax) {
    lenMax = len;
    idxMax = idx;
  }
  return { idx: idxMax, len: lenMax };
}

var luecke = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0];
console.log(nonzero(luecke));
console.log(nonzero([0,0,0,0]));
console.log(nonzero([1,1,1,1]));
```